# Error with React Stripe split card elements: Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, stripe-payments

#### Summary

I have stripped my app down to the bare components and have found that my issue is from the split React Stripe Elements. This implementation was working with a previous app just fine, so something might have changed with implementation of these elements.

#### App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import history from './history';
import Routes from "./routes";

import { Elements, StripeProvider } from "react-stripe-elements";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <StripeProvider apiKey="pk_test_xxxxxx">
        <Elements>
          <Router history={history}>
            <Routes />
          </Router>
        </Elements>
      </StripeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

#### Routes.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Switch, withRouter, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Billing from './components/pages/account/billing/Billing';

export class Routes extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={() => <Billing />} />
            </Switch>
        );
    }
}


export default withRouter(Routes);
```

#### Billing.js

```
import React from "react";
import {CardNumberElement, CardExpiryElement, CardCVCElement, injectStripe} from 'react-stripe-elements';

class Billing extends React.Component {
  render() {

      return (
        <div>
              <CardNumberElement/>
                <CardExpiryElement />
                <CardCVCElement />
        </div>
      );

  }
}

export default injectStripe(Billing);
```

#### packages.json

```
{
  "name": "xxxxxxx",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "filepond": "^4.7.4",
    "filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation": "^1.0.6",
    "filepond-plugin-image-preview": "^4.5.0",
    "firebase": "^7.2.3",
    "formik": "^2.0.3",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-burger-menu": "^2.6.11",
    "react-confirm": "^0.1.18",
    "react-dnd": "^5.0.0",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^3.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-filepond": "^7.0.1",
    "react-firebase-file-uploader": "^2.4.3",
    "react-flexbox-grid": "^2.1.2",
    "react-ga": "^2.7.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.8.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.11.1",
    "react-responsive": "^8.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "react-stripe-elements": "^6.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "^5.4.0",
    "react-with-separator": "^1.2.0",
    "yup": "^0.27.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

#### Error

[image]

Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: post the code of CardNumberElement?

Comment: @v2103 CardNumberElement component is apart of the react-stripe-elements library

Comment: This part of code looks ok. You have setState or something like dispatch action inside lifecycle methods or in render method. Also I'm not hundered 100% sure if 'react-stripe-elements' is a good choice - dependencies are up to date, but code stays unchanged for two years and issues are still there.

Comment: @Zydnar sorry but what do you mean code stays unchanged for 2 years? I see there have been changes in the last few months on the react-stripe-elements GitHub page

Comment: Ok, my bad, most part of code changed. But you're using different versions of dependencies eg. different react versions - this may be the issue.

Comment: @DangerDoug do you get any warnings while installing dependencies?

Comment: @Zydnar Okay, not 100% if I want to downgrade react, but how do I do so to test?

Comment: @Zydnar the only error I get is `gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1` when I run npm install again

Comment: @DangerDoug first thing you can do - delete node_modules and run npm install again. This may be some dependency issue. npm audit also may help you but don't use force fix for audit - it can make breaking changes in dependencies.

Comment: @Zydnar tried deleting node modules and reinstalling and didn't fix the issue. I've had the gyp error for awhile and can't figure out how to solve it, so don't think that is it.

Comment: Modules integration: checked. Now the case with incompatible dependencies versions. Inside package.json from react-stripe-elements you have strict versions as requirement and some of them are written in lower versions than you use. Try downgrade.

Comment: @Zydnar okay, the main one we are looking at is react version but I don’t see anywhere online on how to downgrade that.

Comment: @DangerDoug it's pretty simple - edit package json to contain desired dependency version, in some cases delete lock file and delete node_modules to run npm install again

Comment: @Zydnar yeah I tried to just change the version number in package.json to their version of react/-dom and reinstalled and still didn’t work.

Comment: This is strange. Maybe somethings wrong with node or npm...? Did you tried to delete lock file first?

Comment: @Zydnar thanks for exploring this with me! mathieu found a solution below

Comment: @douglasrcjames I'm glad. This seems now obvious. But what about this `gyp ERR! stack Error:` did you solved it?

Comment: @Zydnar yes actually I did! I had to run ‘sudo Xcode-select —reset’ to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `Elements` component updates its state when a nested Stripe `Element` gets mounted, causing `Router` to be re-rendered, causing the unmounting and remounting of the `Billing` and its sub-`Element`s, causing the loop.

Putting the `Elements` component inside the `Route` should solve the problem.

For example in **Route.js**:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Switch, withRouter, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { Elements } from 'react-stripe-elements';
import Billing from './components/pages/account/billing/Billing';

export class Routes extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={() => <Elements><Billing /></Elements>} />
            </Switch>
        );
    }
}


export default withRouter(Routes);
```